# Getting 2 build command errors from 'YogaKit' in Pods. How do I resolve these 2 errors?

Tags: node.js, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, apple-m1

I am trying to use `npx react-native run-ios`, and I am getting this error;

```
    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'YogaKit' from project 'Pods')
    CompileSwift normal arm64 /Users/myUser/Desktop/myProject-mobile/ios/Pods/YogaKit/YogaKit/Source/YGLayoutExtensions.swift (in target 'YogaKit' from project 'Pods')
(2 failures)
```

Nothing that I have tried so far has fixed the issue, like reinstalling pods, clearing cache, etc. Here is what I am using for development.

Apple M1 Chip
8GB RAM

I appreciate any help with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to exclude `arm64` from the simulator architectures. Don't ask me why... the simulator doesn't seem to like building for arm64.

[image: Build Settings / Excluded Architectures]